# How do I click delete that particular row where text is available?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, visual-studio-code

Image :

[image]

I have to click the delete tab where the text is located as "goregaon-vashi". I tried using sibling also but got failed.

```
<table class="table table-hover txCustomTable" data-ng-show="!fetchingTxTableData" style="">
        <tbody style="margin-top: 0px;">
            <!-- ngRepeat: currentRow in tableRows --><tr data-ng-repeat="currentRow in tableRows" data-ng-class="currentRow.activeClass" class="ng-scope" style="">
                <!-- ngRepeat: currentColumn in metadata.columns --><td data-ng-repeat="currentColumn in metadata.columns" data-ng-class="currentColumn.dataClass" class="ng-scope emp-col-name">
                    <p compile="currentRow[currentColumn.dbCol].displayHtml"><a class="customerDetailsLink ng-scope" data-ng-click="callerScope.onShowStopOnMap($parent.currentRow.stop_points)">goregaon-vashi</a></p>
                                  </td><!-- end ngRepeat: currentColumn in metadata.columns --><td data-ng-repeat="currentColumn in metadata.columns" data-ng-class="currentColumn.dataClass" class="ng-scope emp-col-actions">
                    <p compile="currentRow[currentColumn.dbCol].displayHtml"><a href="/client1/shuttle/routes/create?code=10214" class="ng-scope">Edit</a><a style="margin-left:10px;" data-ng-click="callerScope.onDeleteButtonPress('10214')" class="ng-scope">Delete</a></p>
                </td><!-- end ngRepeat: currentColumn in metadata.columns -->
                              </td><!-- end ngRepeat: currentColumn in metadata.columns -->
            </tr><!-- end ngRepeat: currentRow in tableRows -->
        </tbody><tbody>
    </tbody></table>
```

I tried the path like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'goregaon-vashi')]/following-sibling:://*[contains(text(),'Delete')]")).click();
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the xpath what you mentioned above by inspecting web page?
Does this xpath what you mentioned is highlighting the web element of Delete?

I have tried same by copying your HTML and it is not..

You can use this xpath to identify the Delete:

```
//a[contains(.,'goregaon-vashi')]/../../..//*[.='Delete']
```

Here, Delete element is not a sibling of 'goregaon-vashi' element. Hence, we have to navigate its parent element and should using following-sibling concept.

Comment: Here, you are clicking on Delete or Edit? Why because Delete is not a link, but Edit is.. Also, share the error or exception what you got when you tried to click on Delete..

Comment: Try with this: //a[contains(.,'goregaon-vashi')]/../../..//*[.='Delete']. This xpath will identify  'goregaon-vash' row delete button uniquely even though you have other rows with Delete button

Answer (score 1):

With XPath like this, there are generally a number of approaches that will work. Here's how I approach locators like this.

I try to find an element that is a parent of both of the elements that I need to reference, the element that contains the text I'm looking for 'goregaon-vashi' and then the Delete link. If you look at the HTML, you will see that both of these elements are in the same table row, `TR`. Since the two desired elements are not in the same DOM branch, we need to find the `TR` that contains one, and then navigate down the other DOM branch to the Delete link.

First we find the `TR` that has an `A` tag that contains the 'goregaon-vashi' text. If all we wanted was the 'goregaon-vashi' link, the XPath would look like

```
//tr//a[.='goregaon-vashi']
```

In order to return the `TR`, we need to alter the XPath slightly to

```
//tr[.//a[.='goregaon-vashi']]
    ^                        ^
    these extra braces indicate the property that the `TR` should contain
```

If you run just this, you will see that it returns the parent `TR`... which is exactly what we want for this step. In the next step we go down the DOM to the Delete link from the `TR` we found in the first step.

```
//tr[.//a[.='goregaon-vashi']]//a[.='Delete']
                              ^ this starts the new part
```

If you are familiar with XPath, this should look familiar to you. It's a simple search to any level `//` looking for a `A` tag that contains the exact text 'Delete'.

Hopefully that makes sense. I tested this on the HTML you posted and it returned the correct element.